# Can't assign elements of structure array correctly in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm a beginner at C and I'm having some trouble with this.
I'm trying to mimic the behabiour of an automatic fast food order machine.
When I print the elements of the product array they are all the same.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct{
    char name[12];
    float prize;
}PRODUCT;

typedef struct{
    unsigned prodAmount;
    unsigned orderNumber;
    PRODUCT prod[10];
}ORDER;

void menu(ORDER*);
int main() //main
{
    ORDER currentOrder = {currentOrder.prodAmount = 0};
    menu(&currentOrder);
    return 0;
}
void menu(ORDER*currentOder){
    char option;
    float total;
    do{
        total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < currentOder->prodAmount; i++) total += currentOder->prod->prize;
        system("clear");
        printf("Welcome!\n");
        printf("What would you like today?\n");
        printf("1-. BURGER      3.99$\n");
        printf("2-. CHIPS       0.99$\n");
        printf("3-. DRINK       1.99$\n");
        printf("4-. 6 NUGGETS   2.99$\n");
        printf("5-. ICE CREAM   2.99$\n");
        printf("6-. MENU        5.99$\n");
        printf("0-. PAY\n");
        printf("Products:   %i\n", currentOder->prodAmount);
        printf("TOTAL:      %f$\n", total);
        while((option = getchar()) == '\n');
        switch (option){
            case '1':   strcpy(currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].name, "Hamburger");
                        currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].prize = 3.99;
                        break;
            case '2':   strcpy(currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].name, "Chips");
                        currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].prize = 0.99;
                        break;
            case '3':   strcpy(currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].name, "Drink");
                        currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].prize = 1.99;
                        break;
            case '4':   strcpy(currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].name, "Nuggets");
                        currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].prize = 2.99;
                        break;
            case '5':   strcpy(currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].name, "Ice cream");
                        currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].prize = 2.99;
                        break;
            case '6':   strcpy(currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].name, "Menu");
                        currentOder->prod[currentOder->prodAmount].prize = 5.99;
        }
        currentOder->prodAmount++;
    }while(option != '0' && currentOder->prodAmount < 10);
    system("clear");
    printf("Your order:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < currentOder->prodAmount-1; i++) printf("%s\t%f$\n", currentOder->prod->name, currentOder->prod->prize);
    printf("TOTAL: %f\n", total);
}
```

This is a static array of structures so I think I don't have to use malloc. I can't see what is not working. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

When you have an array:

```
struct X a[10];
```

then all these lines do the same thing:

```
a[0].field = 1;
(*a).field = 1;
a->field = 1;
```

This is the problem with your loop printing the elements of the `prod` array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < currentOder->prodAmount-1; i++)
    printf("%s\t%f$\n", currentOder->prod->name, currentOder->prod->prize);
```

You should use `i` as an index instead, because the compiler won't do that for you:

```
for(int i = 0; i < currentOder->prodAmount-1; i++)
    printf("%s\t%f$\n", currentOder->prod[i].name, currentOder->prod[i].prize);
```

There is a similar mistake where you calculate the `total`.

Comment: Also `i < currentOder->prodAmount-1` should be `i < currentOder->prodAmount`.

Comment: @Barmar only if the OP actually wants to print the last one.

Comment: Oh yeah thank you I completely missed that.